# for loop with ifelse statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset containing as.factor type data for species genus GEN and level of decay DECAY
I want to calculate the AGB for every individual row using data from these 2 columns 
The first set of code only using GEN ran succesfully creating an AGB column storing a AGB value for every specimen.
The second set of code does not run. I left out the 2 other genus to avoid repetitiveness here. The error is pasted at the end. 
Any tips on why the same approach does not work upon adding a condition.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat$GEN[i] =='Avicennia'){
    dat$AGB[i]<- 140*dat$dbh[i]^2.44
  }else if (dat$GEN[i]=='Laguncularia'){
    dat$AGB[i]<- 100.23*dat$dbh[i]^2.53
  }else if (dat$GEN[i]=='Rhizophora'){
    dat$AGB[i]<-128.23*dat$dbh[i]^2.61
  }
}
```

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat$GEN[i] =='Avicennia'& dat$DECAY[i]==0){
    dat$AGB[i]<- 0.14*dat$dbh[i]^2.4
  }else if (dat$GEN[i]=='Avicennia'& dat$DECAY[i]==0.5){
    dat$AGB[i]<- 0.9875*0.14*dat$dbh[i]^2.4
  }else if (dat$GEN[i]=='Avicennia' & dat$DECAY[i]==1){
    dat$AGB[i]<-0.975*0.14*dat$dbh[i]^2.4
  }else if (dat$GEN[i]=='Avicennia'& dat$DECAY[i]==2){
    dat$AGB[i]<-0.8*0.14*dat$dbh[i]^2.4
  }else if (dat$GEN[i]=='Avicennia'& dat$DECAY[i]==3){
    dat$AGB[i]<-0.070*dat$dbh[i]^2.4
  }
}
```

```
Error in if (dat$GEN[i] == "Avicennia" & dat$DECAY[i] == 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Instead of `if/else`, it may be more efficient with `ifelse`. Regardig the error, please consider to show a small reproducible example with `dput` for testing.  Also, the `dat$AGB[i] <- can be taken outside of the loop and assign only once i.e. `dat$AGB[i] <- if(dat$GEN[i] =='Avicennia'& dat$DECAY[i]==0){0.14*dat$dbh[i]^2.4} else if(dat$GEN[i]=='Avicennia'& dat$DECAY[i]==0.5){...}`

Comment: Could you please add a reproducable sample of your data. That is crucial to identify the error. Use e.g. `dput(dat)` or at least  `dput(head(dat))` and post the result.

My first hunch would be that you have `NA`s in your data. That produces this error. In that case you could check with `if( !is.na(dat$GEN) && !is.na(dat$DECAY)) { # your code }`

Comment: @Jan you were right there was some missing data for DECAY. I already filterd it out but did not run the filtercode this time. THANKS!

Comment: @Akrun Although i've solved the immediate issue i would like to try a shorter cleaner looking code. Do you have any good ifelse links. Thanks Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use a compact version, either `ifelse` (nested) or a `case_when` would be more appropriate

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   mutate(AGB = case_when(
              GEN == 'Avicennia' & DECAY == 0 & !is.na(DECAY) ~ 0.14* dbh^2.4,
              GEN == 'Avicennia' & DECAY == 0.5 & !is.na(DECAY) ~ 0.9875 *0.14* dbh^2.4,
              GEN == 'Avicennia' & DECAY == 1 & !is.na(DECAY) ~ 0.975 *0.14* dbh^2.4,
              GEN == 'Avicennia' & DECAY == 2 & !is.na(DECAY) ~ 0.8 *0.14* dbh^2.4,
              GEN == 'Avicennia' & DECAY == 3 & !is.na(DECAY) ~ 0.07 *0.14* dbh^2.4,
              TRUE ~ as.numeric(AGB))
```

NOTE: There is always a risk involved when we try to compare (`==`) with a floating value i.e. 0.5.  Make sure the values are exact and doesn't involve any precision

---

Another option is to use a named vector to match the values in 'DECAY' and then do the calculation based on matching the values

```
nm1 <- setNames(c(1, 0.9875, 0.975, 0.8, 0.07), c(0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3))
i1 <- dat$GEN == 'Avicennia'
dat$AGB[i1] <- with(dat, nm1[as.character(DECAY[i1])] * 0.14 * dbh[i1]^2.4)
```